# Python process file and return specific items

Tags: python, file, twitter, python-twitter

Say i have a dict, dict is a dictonary with dictonary as value

```
dict = {'**Leon**':{'Name':'Leon L','**follow**':['Apple', 'PPy','Jack','Tommy']},'**Jack**':{'name':'Jack Y','**follow**':['Apple','Cruise','Jay']},'**Tommy**':{'name':'Tommy T','**follow**':['Hill']},'**Apple**':{'name':'Apple A','**follow**':['Jack']},**'Cruise'**:{'name':'Cruise L','**follow**':['Jay']}}
```

`**follow**` means users that is followed by this user, for example:
Leon follows Apple, PPy,Jack,Tommy

and i have query file that has tasks in it. We need to accomplish the task and return a list of usernames (the usernames are the keys in dict, eg 'Leon','Jack','Tommy'), the format of that file is:

```
SEARCH
Leon
follow
follow-by # there might be many more follow, and follow-by
FILTER
name-include Leon
follow Apple # format: keyword follow, a space and a username. same apply to follow-by username
follow-by Leon # there might be more name-include, , follow username, follow by username
```

the meaning of the query file:
The SEARCH and FILTER are keywords. The line after SEARCH is the starting username (we need to put it in the list, lets name the list user_list). The search specification has the 2 steps (in this case):

1. create a list that has Leon in it, call this list L1
2. follow says to replace each person p in L1 with people who follows p, then we get L2
3. follow-by says to replace each person p in L2 with people who are followed by p (people who are followed by p are in the follow list of the user profile). Then we get L3

The filter specification (in this example):

1. for each person p in L3, if p's name has 'Leon' in it, the user is kept in the list.Then we get L4
2. for each person p in L4, if p follows Apple, then p is kept in the list, we get L5
3. for each person p in L5, if p is followed by Leon, p is kept in the list. Then we get our final    list. We need to return the final list

**Can anyone help me to write a program that can accomplish the task?**

Comment: It would be nice if you showed us what you had so far or tell us what you are stuck on.  We aren't here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a state machine, or more specifically [pushdown automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton). You would initialize the machine with the data dict, then for every line in the input file, you will transition into a new state and do the work specified, storing the result in the stack. Every step can access the data returned from the previous step.